# Equinox started notification

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox

### Backgroud

I'm using Equinox from within the Eclipse IDE to run a group of bundles (some of them are projects in my Eclipse working set).

After launching Equinox I would like to run some service. One option would be to use the Console which works fine, but, I would like to run something *automatically* after hitting the "run" button, instead of writing a command in the console window again every time.

Another special thing about the service I want to run is that it consumes another service *that can only be resolved in run-time*. During run-time my application checks who could provide some service and chooses between the service providers. This means that:

- I can run my application only after all bundles were installed and started.
- I cannot know in advance (in compile-time) which bundles my application depends on. The service provider is chosen according to run-time parameters.

### My Question is:

**Is there a way to register some notification in order to know when Equinox completed installing and starting all bundles its supposed to during its start-up?**

If there is such a hook, I could use it to know when I could start my application.

Comment: Why not write your application such that it only starts *itself* when it detects that the services it wants are available? Then you can start the bundles in any order.

Comment: @NeilBartlett The application "doesn't know" which bundles it needs, it only knows that it should run a service (that could be provided by many bundles). The fact that the service that my application wants is available doesn't mean that all the necessary bundles were started (maybe only some of them).

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me yet.... why does your application need bundles? Bundles are deployment artifacts and they shouldn't be visible at the application layer. Application code uses services, and the services you need will be provided by bundles when they start. What does it mean for the "necessary" bundles not to have started? In what sense are they "necessary"?

Comment: @NeilBartlett Without getting into the details, the application iterates through all the possible providers of a specific service. If another bundle which implements this service is deployed, the application could find it and use it without explicitly specifying this in the application itself. The application does not know in advance how many service providers will be consumed by it. The application doesn't care about "Bundles" but it does care about providers of this specific service. The Bundles are necessary in the sense that each of them is a provider of this specific service.

Comment: Are these multiple instances of the same service? It sounds like you're saying the application needs to start after "all N" service instances become available, but you don't know in advance what the value of N will be. Does that sound right? Also, are you in control of the launcher of the application? The problem from Equinox is it doesn't know in advance how many bundles you will install. If *you* control the launcher that installs/starts bundles, then *you* know when you are done.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Yes these are multiple instances of the same service, but the application doesn't need to start after any specific "N" service instances. The application can work with any number of instances of the service, but for my purpose I need it to start after all my bundles were started (these are my projects in the working set). Am I in control of the launcher? in a way I am: the launcher is eclipse and launching is clicking the "run" button in ecplise. I don't install any other bundles after running.

Comment: Again I don't really get why your application cares about the bundles starting rather than the services they publish. I think I may have enough information to answer the question now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Found it.

Register a [Framework Event](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/FrameworkEvent.html) on the Bundle's activator by calling [context.addFrameworkListener](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#addFrameworkListener%28org.osgi.framework.FrameworkListener%29), and start the application when [STARTED](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/FrameworkEvent.html#STARTED) event is fired.

Works well, I just wonder whether I need to start the application on a new thread or maybe I could start my application directly from the event handler.

Comment: This might work for your case but does not work universally. For example Apache Karaf first uses a lower initial start level. It then waits to acquire a cluster lock. IF the lock is achieved it sets the start level to a higher level to start to application bundles. So the framework started event would arrive too early. 
But still .. it might be a good solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very common problem in OSGi when trying to build extensibility into your application. Let us see if I understood correctly.

You have a service interface that is used to provide some kind of extension for your bundle. Your bundle should run when all extensions have loaded.

So the problem is that you do not known when all bundles are up. Btw. if the bundles providing the service impls are using e.g. blueprint then their bundle can be Active while the blueprint extender did not yet run. So there is probably no solution to really determine when all bundles are fully started.

So in this environment there are two possible solutions:

1. Your bundle starts to work with the existing services and listens for additional ones to come and does the necessary work to integrate these
2. You can describe in configuration which extensions should be there. In this case each extension can register their service using a unique name in the service properties. You can then define in the config of your bundle which names need to be present before your bundle really starts.

Case 2 is used for example in CXF DOSGi. There a service endpoint can specifiy named "intents" it needs. The service endpoint is then only published when all intents are present in form of services with these names. This case is for example useful if you have a security service and your bundle may not start without it as it would be unsecured then.

Apart from these two variants I do not know of any reliable mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is still a thing that is not clear to me though. Suppose my application requires a service (which service, we only know on *runtime*), and this service is not available. Should it wait until its available (perhaps not all bundles were loaded yet) or should it give an error? If it waits, it could wait forever if it's never available. But if it gives an error, maybe the service will be available in a moment when the OSGi container completes its startup? Do you see the problem and why I need an indication of `Equinox startup completed` before I start my application?

Comment: You can do this with a timeout. In cxf dosgi I solved it like this. See http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/dosgi/trunk/dsw/cxf-dsw/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/dosgi/dsw/qos/IntentManagerImpl.java the method is assertAllIntentsSupported. If you use blueprint to bind a simple service you can define it as mandatory. This also makes it timeout and give an error.

Comment: This is a valid solution but not a pretty one. Feels more like a workaround, feels like there is some unclosed design issue that forces me to do that. What would the timeout be? 1 second? 1 minute? Do we need to guess how much time it should take the OSGi container to start up? If we take the worse case scenario for start-up time (say - one minute), what about the user experience, who needs to wait a whole minute or so in order to know there was something wrong, instead of getting an error right away as soon as start-up is completed? The more I think about this the less I like this idea.

Comment: I also think it is not very pretty but as there is no notification on startup we currently have no better solution. To be fair there is no such thing as startup in OSGi as you can add and remove bundles at any time. The question though is how many applications really need such a dynamic environment. Btw. in apache karaf I created a service that is registered when all bundles are active. See: https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/features/core/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/features/BootFinished.java?source=cc . We use this in itests

Comment: I found a better solution - registering a framework event. See my answer.